# Text with date, how to convert?

Tags: text, date-and-time

I use this script to recognise a date in a textfile and write the result in another file.

```
For[i = 1, i < 20, i++,
  test1 = Import["E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\" <> ToString[i] <>".txt", "Text"];
  test2 = {StringCases[test1, DatePattern[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}]],
         StringCases[ToLowerCase[test1], RegularExpression["\\w(?<!\\d)[\\w'-]*"]]};
Write[s, test2]];
```

The result is a file like this:

[image: example data file]

```
test3 = ReadList["E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\testfile3.txt"]
```

Then I would like to make a selection on the date/first column. In this example, mathematica don't recognise it as a datastring. I tried to convert it like

```
DateString[test3[[All, 1]]]
```

but that  didnt work. Who has a suggestion?

Comment: Please post the actual data so we can work with it rather than having to make it up.

Comment: {{"2013/12/18"}, {"a", "b", "c"}}
 {{"1999/11/16"}, {"b", "c", "d"}}
 {{"1994/02/18"}, {"c", "d", "e"}}
 {{"1998/04/26"}, {"f", "g", "h"}}
 {{"1998/11/10"}, {"i", "j", "k"}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to work with the date you should convert it to a date list. Example:

```
    res = {{{"2013/12/8"}, {"a", "b"}}, {{"2013/12/8"}, {"a", "b"}}};
    res2 = MapAt[DateList@First@# &, res, {All, 1}]
(* Out: {{{2013, 12, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {"a", "b"}}, {{2013, 12, 8, 0, 0, 
   0.}, {"a", "b"}}} *)
```

Now you can use `Select` or `Cases` or whatever to extract data. If you just want to use `DateString` on each date then you could do it like this: `DateString /@ res2[[All, 1]]`.

Comment: Hi Pickett, Thanks for your reply. The file I used is very large so I import the file with: test3 = ReadList[
      "E:\\data\\MC1 Data\\MC1 Data\\articles\\testfile3.txt"]; If I try next:     ReadList[StringToStream[test3[[All, 1]]]]; the result is $Failed

Comment: @MichielvanMens I updated my code to avoid confusion. I only used `ReadList` to make my example the same as yours. I don't think that part is necessary in order to answer the question, correct me if I'm wrong. After you've used `ReadList` you should have a list as in `res` in my example.